# maven-compiler-plugin report generation

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I would like to capture warnings/errors generated by maven-compiler-plugin (when running compile goal) and output them to a file (be it xml or json). I would then like to view the file on CI console. By default, maven-compiler-plugin doesn't provide the option to configure a reporter. So, curious to know how this can be done. Here's my plugin config -

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You will get the output in the console output on your ci console...which can be analysed via reporting tools on CI (for example Jenkins Next Generation Warning plugin)...

Comment: Im curious to know if we can configure some reporting plugin in POM and capture compile step output.

Comment: As far as I know. No...